# How to create a three-column list in with items arranged vertically

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, grid

I have a problem to style a ul using display: grid. The list should look like the picture below. Elements in this ul can have different heights.
[Expected behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6FIJ.png)

So far I've added a styles for
ul: grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr and grid-auto-flow: column.
For li elements, depending on in which column element should be:
grid-column: 1 or grid-column: 2 or grid-column: 3.

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: columns;
  row-gap: 10px;
  column-gap: 10px;
}

.first-column {
  grid-column: 1;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: skyblue;
}

.second-column {
  grid-column: 2;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.third-column {
  grid-column: 3;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
  <ul class="wrapper">
    <li class="first-column"></li>
    <li class="first-column"></li>
    <li class="second-column"></li>
    <li class="second-column"></li>
    <li class="third-column"></li>
    <li class="third-column"></li>
  </ul>
```

However, this causes the row height to be determined by the highest element in the row. Just like in the picture below.

[current behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lRaM.png)

Comment: Hi @Przemekr can you add your code, which you have tried so far.

Comment: @Przemerk the code that you put has only 6 `li`s but your expected output has 11.

Comment: @TheMyth Because the number of elements will be different depending on what the API returns. I get three different arrays of objects that I put in one ul. Each arrays of objects is one column

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it:

```css
.grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100px 200px 100px;
    column-gap: 50px; /* The gap you want */
}
.col{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 100px);
    row-gap: 100px; /* The gap you want */
}
.col.spec{
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 200px);
    row-gap: 50px; /* The gap you want */
}
.elm{
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="elm"></div>
    <div class="elm"></div>
    <div class="elm"></div>
    <div class="elm"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col spec">
    <div class="elm"></div>
    <div class="elm"></div>
    <div class="elm"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="elm"></div>
    <div class="elm"></div>
    <div class="elm"></div>
    <div class="elm"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can always adjust the stylings and dimensions as you want but make sure to make it responsive.

Comment: However, I need to put all the elements in one ul. Can you help me in this case?

Comment: What do you mean? Can you please provide your HTML for the same.

Comment: I have added html and css example to my question.